# Flex-box items get under upper div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

It might be something stupid that I'm not seeing. But I can't figure this one out.

I have this landing, with a sticky footer and a flex-box wrapper on two columns that makes them stick to the bottom of its wrapper and stay to the bottom while you resize to make the screen bigger.

The problem is, when I make the screen smaller the columns get under the navigation div even if their wrapper starts after the navigation div.

What I want is for the columns to not get under the navigation div when the user resizes into a smaller size screen. And instead, for the browser to automatically add a y-scroll.

This is the structure:

```css
.main_wrapper{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.content_wrapper{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height:calc(100vh - 60px);
  background:black;
}

footer{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background:#4096ee;
  height:60px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
}

nav{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background:yellow;
  color:#000;
  text-align:center;
  height:60px;
  opacity:0.8;
}

.landing_content{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background:green;
  height:100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row; 
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.col1{
  float:left;
  width:36%;
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
  height: 400px;
}

.col2{
    float: left;
    width: 64%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main_wrapper">
    <div class="content_wrapper">
      <nav>
        A navigation
      </nav>
      <div class="landing_content">
        <div class="col1">
          A content column
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          Second content column
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      A footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is the codepen:

https://codepen.io/Luciellav/pen/mWrzOz/

Thanx a lot.

Comment: Add `overflow: auto` to `.landing_content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give `.landing_content` a `min-height` the same as the *content column*:

```
.landing_content {
  ...
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Sadly with that, the footer now doesn't stick to the bottom. It makes what happened at the top, now happens at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

As @caisah suggested. It works if both `.landing_content` and `.content_wrapper` get the `min-height` of the columns:

```css
.content_wrapper{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height:calc(100vh - 60px);
  background:black;
  min-height:400px;
}

.landing_content{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background:green;
  height:100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row; 
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
  min-height:400px;
}
```

Working on the same codepen:

https://codepen.io/Luciellav/pen/mWrzOz